# How do you rewrite a page to your homepage?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

I am trying to redirect https://www.example.com/index.html to https://www.example.com

and i've tried ../ and / and https://www.example.com but none of these work as target path. [image: url form]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Magento Root `.htaccess` file  & it should be index.php

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Change it to

```
RewriteRule .* index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Reindexing the site fixed this issue